# knockout js form data empty

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms, knockout.js

I'm new to Knockout JS, I'm trying to get the form data from the fields When I hit submit, I get an empty object with no data from the form.

I would like to know if i'm missing something here?

project type is WEB API ASP.net, here is my code:

```
 <form id="frmUsuario" method="post" data-bind="submit:agregarUsuario" style="border-radius: 0px;">
 </form>
```

JS Function:

```
self.agregarUsuario = function () {

     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: pathApi + "/ApiUsuario/addUsuario",
            data: form.serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Record added Successfully");

            }
        })
}
```

Comment: Try to check `form.serialize()` like `alert(Json.Stringify(form.serialize()))` if it has a content or not.

Comment: I keep getting null..but the form has information in every field..

Comment: What is `form` in your ajax? Where is that defined?

Comment: i changed form for the following, and still could not get anything: $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: pathApi + "/ApiUsuario/addUsuario",
            data: $("#frmUsuario").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Record added Successfully");
            }
        })

Comment: Still could not get anything means what? Are you getting an error? Are  you getting null? Is the form with id "frmUsuario" defined??

Comment: i got it! it was the name of the fields.. they have to be lowercase.. haha stupid mistakes.. but still its a good lesson. Thanks everyone!